# C++ File reading speed unsatisfactory

Tags: c++, performance, file-read

This code takes on average 1.2 seconds to execute on a 10.1GB file, this is unacceptable, this should imo take 200ms, I have stuff to do I'm not waiting a day for this to execute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>  // chrono related code removed
#include <immintrin.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE (384 * 1024)

using namespace std;

inline int count_avx2(const char* begin, const char* end, char target) {
    const __m256i avx2_Target = _mm256_set1_epi8(target);
    const char* ptr = begin;
    int result = 0;

    for (; ptr + 63 < end; ptr += 64) {
        _mm_prefetch(ptr + 128, _MM_HINT_T0);
        __m256i chunk1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(ptr));
        __m256i chunk2 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(ptr + 32));
        __m256i cmp_result1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(chunk1, avx2_Target);
        __m256i cmp_result2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(chunk2, avx2_Target);
        int mask1 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp_result1);
        int mask2 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp_result2);
        result += _mm_popcnt_u32(mask1);
        result += _mm_popcnt_u32(mask2);
    }

    return result;
}

int counter(const string& filename) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Error: Couldn't open file " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int totalNewlines = 0;
    size_t bytesRead;

    while (!feof(file)) {
        bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);

        totalNewlines += count_avx2(buffer, buffer + bytesRead, '\n');
    }

    fclose(file);

    return totalNewlines;
}

int main() {
    string filename = "output.txt";
    int newlineCount = counter(filename);

    if (newlineCount >= 0) {
        cout << "Number of newlines in " << filename << ": " << newlineCount << endl;
    } else {
        cerr << "Error counting newlines in file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any opinions on how to make this faster?

I tried using fstream, memory mapping and Windows's built in io.h neither of these was faster than 1 second or satisfied my requirements, the count algo is fine, it takes ~100ms cumulative

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlzNj.png

Comment: 10.1 GB in 1.2 seconds equates to 8.4 GB/s ... That's faster reading than most SSDs I'm aware of ... And 1.2 seconds is by no definition "waiting a day"

Comment: For best I/O performance, don't let the stream stop.  I recommend using a thread to read and a thread for processing.  Use multiple buffering to help synchronize the threads.  If your platform has DMA capability for the file, use it.

Comment: There is a very slight off chance that when you use boost::asio with a buffer size equal to DMA size of the disk you can eke out a bit more. But before trying that... What is the theoretical maximum througput speed of your drive in the first place?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes that what boost asio allows setup a few buffers up front read to them on one thread then round-robin. Reuse processed buffers for your next reads.

Comment: @ChrisMM I was asking how to make it faster not how fast it already is (which it isn't) 

Comment: You're missing the point of my comment. Your drive is likely not capable of reading any more than what it currently is reading at. Unless you have a Gen 5 PCIe SSD with a compatible processor and mother board, you are at the limit. And, I believe, the fastest SSD is 12GB/s. You are asking to read at 50GB/s which is simply not possible with today's technology.

Comment: @PepijnKramer If I remember correctly its 4,500MB/s

Comment: Besides the mechanics of your "hard drive", your next bottleneck is the databus contention.  I was able to get very high efficiency by using the CPU data caches.  If your platform has memory on the chip (but not inside the processor) fill that up too.  In your search function, work on block sizes that are the size of the processor's cache.  You want the devices that are sharing the data bus, to pass as much data as possible before yielding to another device; always blocks.

Comment: @Majmac Then it looks like further optimization is not needed. But to be sure you need to run a profiler to find your real bottlenecks

Comment: Your comment states that the drive bandwidth is 4,500MB/s (~4.5GB/s) but you claim in your question that you're already achieving 8.4 GB/s.  With all due respect, I think you need to check a few numbers -- theoretical and measured.

Comment: @G.M. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlzNj.png

Comment: For maximum throughput organize your file, on the medium, so that it doesn't have to jump to find blocks.  The read head and track should be making least amount of movements.  Optimal drives will have the file header loaded into a cache before reading, to speed up the location of the next block of file data.  Also, keep the drive spinning. There is a loss of time waiting for the drive to get up to speed again.

Comment: OK, so your comment stating that the maximum throughput is 4500MB/s is probably not correct.  You really need to find out what it *is* and use that as a goal.

Comment: @G.M. https://www.micron.com/products/ssd/product-lines/2400 Micron states 4500MB/s for the 1TB drive which is the one I have

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if part of the file is cached elsewhere if you've run it several times. In either case, your file is 9.4GB, according to the image, and your program is processing it at 7.5GB/s. Considering your drive is limited to about 4.4 GB/s read, I'd say you're doing pretty good. In any case, you cannot reasonably expect to read a 9.4 GB file in 200ms...

Comment: *"this should imo take 200ms"* -- How did you arrive at this number? It seems rather arbitrary without context.

Comment: @ChrisMM yes, windows will cache the file but in the "standby" part of the RAM, since my ram is running at 3200MT/s I should be able to read the file in roughly 450ms if I include the 70-100ms needed to count the newlines in file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By optimizing the count_avx2 by bitshifting the masks and using popcnt_u64 I was able to get it around ~1s, It's not optimal but its better I guess